# How to create basic connection with UWP app and Azure DB with C#

Tags: c#, azure, uwp, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to connect my windows phone application with azure sql db.
I am following this tutorial [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-add-azure-mobile-app-to-an-uwp-app/).

The web app in microsoft azure receives requests I send after pressing the button. 
but it doesnt save any data.

the mobile app in microsoft azure works fine (see it [here](http://projectpresjawebapp.azurewebsites.net/))

the code under main.xaml.cs is:

```
    IMobileServiceTable<UsernameTB> UsernameTBObj = App.MobileService.GetTable<UsernameTB>();
    private void btnSave_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            UsernameTB obj = new UsernameTB();
            obj.Username = txtUsernameField.Text;
            obj.Password = txtPasswordField.Text;

            UsernameTBObj.InsertAsync(obj);
            MessageDialog msgDialog = new MessageDialog("Data Inserted!!!");
            msgDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageDialog msgDialogError = new MessageDialog("Error : " + ex.ToString());
            msgDialogError.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

UsernameTB has this code:

```
 class UsernameTB
    {
        public string id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string Username
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string Password
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

    }
```

whats the problem here?

Comment: Do you really have a datatype `string` for `id`?

Comment: oh no, its int. looks like I missed that part. thanks for reminding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of things it could be.  Turn on diagnostic logging in the backend and use the log stream to monitor for events - do you get errors.

You may benefit from reading Chapter 3 of my book at http://aka.ms/zumobook - this goes into the transactions that actually happen.